# Examples of interesting integrable functions with at least 2 fixed points and an explicit inverse

Tags: calculus, integration, functions, definite-integrals

What are some interesting functions I can use to demonstrate this integration trick:

$$\int_a^b [f(x)+f^{-1}(x)]=b^2-a^2$$

I would like to know of some interesting functions where this trick is not obvious. EDIT: The functions I am receiving are the obvious ones like $f(x)=x$, which I don't want. :)

Comment: you should add that the function is not the identity.

Comment: @8pir Yes, see now.

Comment: $\int_0^1 \left(x^n + \sqrt[n]{x}\right)dt = 1$

Comment: @xavierm02 That is a bit obvious in my opinion, but thanks none the less :)

Comment: The thing is, you can take any function $f$ that's injective on $[a,b]$ and for some $\alpha,\beta$, $g=\alpha f + \beta$ will satisfy $g(a)=a$ and $g(b)=b$ and so if you can express $f^{-1}$, you can compute your intergral for that function...

Comment: For example, $f=\exp$ is injective on $[0,1]$. Let $g(x)=\frac{\exp(x)-1}{e-1}$. $g^{-1}(x)=\ln((e-1)x+1)$. So $\int_0^1\left(\frac{\exp(x)-1}{e-1}+\ln((e-1)x+1)\right)dx = 1$.

Comment: And it works with any $f$ no matter how complicated (as long as you can express its inverse).

Comment: @xavierm02 That is the problem, coming up with good functions with good-looking interesting inverses, with the problem of two fixed points.

Comment: @125a8owp : Define "good-looking" and "interesting". Aside from very basic functions, inverses are *defined* as the inverse of the function and not expressed otherwise. That's often done for $\ln$ (even though there are other definitions), it's the case for the inverse of all trigonometric functions etc.

Comment: You could take weird functions like the Lambert W function but it'd still be the exact same thing: take a weird function, restrict it to an interval where it's injective, scale it and put it in the integral.

Answer (score 3):

Take $$f(x)=x+\sin x$$
Now, if you are asked to find $$\int_{0}^{\pi}f^{-1}(x)dx^{**}$$Do you know $f^{-1*}$,No!
Puzzled! Use the identity:
$$\int_{0}^{\pi}f^{-1}(x)dx=\pi^2-\int_{0}^{\pi}f(x)dx=\frac{\pi^2}2-2$$ 
Otherwise put you can use it anywhere you can't get $f^{-1}$ in explicit forms.

<sub>*in explicit form</sub>

<sub>**$\small f(0)=0\wedge f(\pi)=\pi$</sub>

Answer (score 1):

Well, you can take $f(x)=\sin(\pi x/2)^n$, so that $f^{-1}(x)=2 \arcsin(x^{1/n})/\pi$ and 
$$\int_0^1 f(x)+f^{-1}(x) = 1$$

If you know how to integrate $f$, this allows you to compute the definite integral
$$\int_0^1 \arcsin(x^{1/n})$$

But this might not be what you're looking for, since I suspect you want a case where the function $f+f^{-1}$, as opposed to the function $f^{-1}$, looks like something that might occur naturally.

Answer (score 0):

The first obvious one that satisfies your condition is $f(x)=x$.

Comment: I know, but I am not looking for obvious ones.

Answer (score 0):

I'll throw one in for kicks. This is the first one that came to mind that isn't directly given in the form you stated. It's nothing mind blowing but here we go.

$\int 2xdx = x^2$, obviously. Now let $f(x) = x$. Then we get
\begin{align*}\int_a^b 2xdx & = \int_a^b 2f(x)dx \\
& = \int_a^b (f(x) + f(x))dx \\
& = \int_a^b (f(x) + f^{-1}(x))dx \\
& = b^2 - a^2 \text{,}
\end{align*}

and of course this simply coincides with exactly what we'd expect from $\int_a^b 2xdx$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $a$ and $b$ be greater than or equal to 1. $\int_a^b{e^{x^2}+\sqrt{\ln{x}}dx}=b^2-a^2$