# Are there any interesting applications of $\int_{a}^bf(x)dx+\int_{f(a)}^{f(b)}f^{-1}(x)dx=bf(b)-af(a)$?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration

The [integral identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral_of_inverse_functions) in the title is a very famous one. I used it recently when solving $\int_0^2\left(\sqrt{1+x^3}+\sqrt[3]{x^2+2x}\:\right)dx$. Naturally I wondered if it has any more interesting applications in calculus. Can anyone come up with some uses of this integral identity, either in solving more challenging integrals like the example I have just given or any other application?

Comment: "very famous" is a slight exaggeration, don't you think ?

Comment: @JeanMarie Why do you say that?  I know of it :-)

Comment: Do you mean that it is very famous because **you** know it ? :)

Comment: I'm sure plenty of others know it.  It just comes straight from some nice geometry is all.

Comment: @wrb98 You may also note this only works if $f$ is injective on $[a,b]$.

Comment: I would be interested in seeing a reference for the "famous" integral identity mentioned in the post.

Comment: @Jack It has its own [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral_of_inverse_functions)

Comment: @Simply Beautifull Art I dislike polemics, I just wanted, with a big smile, to say that "famous", "very famous", "(very)$^n$ famous" should be used with parcimony.

Comment: Here is a "proof without words" of the identity for injective functions: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/ch2p1yzq6i  But now I see that the Wikipedia article has a similiar "proof."

Comment: Some examples in this related question: [Examples of interesting integrable functions with at least 2 fixed points and an explicit inverse](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/872348/examples-of-interesting-integrable-functions-with-at-least-2-fixed-points-and-an).

Comment: @JeanMarie I am quite astonished that, despite all the interesting mathematics here, you would much rather discuss a two-word quote from the opening sentence, which has nothing at all to do with the problem at hand! Nevertheless, I stand by the hyperbole, since this identity is familiar to a good proportion of calculus students. I would advise you in the future to hold back from commenting on questions if you have nothing more constructive or relevant to add.